# Printing copy/original (Netsuite)

Tags: oracle, netsuite, erp

how could I print **original** document when printing first time, and a **copy** whenever I print after the first time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When printing a document, a UserEvent is triggered.

You can store a timestamp when it's first printed (or a simple checkbox) on the document.

You can either print the original document or the copy depending on the timestamp/checkbox.

```js
/**
 *@NApiVersion 2.x
 *@NScriptType UserEventScript
*/
define(['N/record'], function(record) {

  function beforeLoad(context) {
    var UserEventType = context.UserEventType;
    var contextType = context.type;
    var newRecord = context.newRecord;

    if (contextType == UserEventType.PRINT) {
      var fieldId = 'custrecord_is_printed' // fieldId of your custom field / checkbox (or use a datetimestamp)

      var isPrinted = newRecord.getValue({ fieldId: fieldId })
      if (!isPrinted) {
        var myRecord = record.load({ type: newRecord.type, id: newRecord.id }) // in the beforeLoad, editing the newRecord is not allowed, so you need to load the record first, edit and save.
        myRecord.setValue({ fieldId: fieldId, value: true })
        myRecord.save()
      }
    }
  }

  return {
      beforeLoad: beforeLoad,
  }

});
```

in your advanced html template use a condition like

```html
<#if record.custrecord_is_printed>
  <p>COPY</p>
<#else>
  <p>ORIGINAL</p>
</#if>
```

Comment: Are you familiar with SuiteScript? see edit above.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42961018/module-does-not-exist-suitescript

Comment: Thank you a lot bro!
let me check it out

Comment: [Look at this error!, the checkbox is checked when i reload the record by editing it and save it and print it but i got this error while i am trying to access the advance template of this transaction (Journal)][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6SscL.png

Comment: The error says, you're missing a required argument 'id' in line 17 of your script. You can use the N/log module to figure out what's causing the error.

Comment: I got it now, but how to check in the template if the checkbox is true or false?

Comment: In your HTML template just include an if statement, like mentioned in my answer.

Comment: I think there is an issue in rendering